# NixOS how to see outdated system packages

Tags: linux, nixos

On NixOS, is there any way to query for outdated system packages?

I know I can query this with `nix-env` for user-installed packages but I can't seem to find a way to know beforehand what will be updated when I run a `nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade`.

I'm thinking about using NixOS for deployment of a couple of servers in production but then I definitely need to be able to know what an upgrade will install before I actually execute it.

Answer (score 1):

To see what will be upgraded you can do "nixos-rebuild dry-build" to see the list of newly built packages.

If you want to deploy to a server, I think it's better to use `nixops` or manually copy packages with `nix-copy` and than call `activation` script `switch-configuration`.